# How do you programatically encrypt SOAP messages in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, soap

I'm creating a SOAPMessage object, and before I send it I want to encrypt the contents. I'm creating it in a similar way to many examples that can be found on SO, for example:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

// Retrieve different parts
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

// Two ways to extract body
SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

//Modify body
// Etc
```

I can't find examples of how to encrypt the contents of an object that I create like this.

Comment: I would say you should not manually encrypt the SOAP message, but instead use the WS-Security standard, so the SOAP clients can decrypt your messages. For example see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html

Answer (score 0):

Soap Encryption is different from normal encryption process we do, as Encrypted XML payload has to be in a standard structure specified by WS-Security.

Use any WS-Security implementation like Axis, WSS4J.